# Don't show custom content types when click on New

Tags: content-type

Business users don't want to show the content type when a user goes to the list/doc lib and clicks on new drop down. I used contypeType.Hidden = true; but it did not work.

http://www.novolocus.com/2009/05/26/control-the-content-types-in-the-new-menu-via-code/

Any other idea?

Comment: What content type are you trying to hide? An OOB one? Custom? How was the custom one created?

Comment: are you talking about New Form or about drop down list with CTs to create before a New Form appear?

Comment: Note that as the referenced article mentions, setting hidden will remove it from the new menu, but *not* the Content Type drop down on the edit form. That may be adequate (but it's not how I'd describe 'hidden'!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that works.

```
SPContentType oCT = spList.ContentTypes[ctName];
oCT.Hidden = true;
oCT.Update();
```

Comment: What is different about this code versus what you did the first time? Did you forget to run the .Update() method?

Comment: @Tim: I had reinstantiate spcontenttype and this time with splist. First time i had to user web.availablecontenttype to associate a specific ct with my splist. then i could hide the custom ct use the code posted. Thanks

Comment: @SiteOwner: R u serious? I have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer. Is this by design or bug?

Comment: it's by design.

Answer (score 1):

Did you call the Update method after setting the Hidden property?

```
contentType.Hidden = true;
contentType.Update();
```